A reductive group is the complexification of a compact subgroup even if not connected?
The definition of a linear algebraic complex reductive group is sometimes using the connectedness hypothesis for the complex algebraic group sometimes not.
Here I use the following definition : a complex affine linear algebraic group $G$ is said to be reductive if the connected component of the identity of its unipotent radical is trivial.
Is the well known following theorem still true without any connectedness hypothesis (for the complex algebraic groups or the real compact ones)?

There is an equivalence of categories between the category of smooth
representations of a compact real Lie group and and the category of
algebraic representations of a complex linear algebraic reductive
groups.

Or the following theorem?

A linear complex algebraic group is reductive if and only if it has an
algebraic compact real form, which is then a maximal compact real Lie
group

The only place I found these theorems without any hypothesis on the connectedness is in Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups by Onishchik & Vinberg, but their definition of reductiveness is based on the reductiveness of the Lie algebra, which does not seem clearly to exclude the case of the $(\mathbb{C}, +)$ group.
I would also like if the hypothesis is necessary a counter-example and if not a good reference.
Edit
I have posted this question on MO at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477745/is-connectedness-necessary-for-a-reductive-group-to-be-the-complexification-of-a
